# Jest threshold for a test to be reported as slow

Tags: jestjs

I use jest to drive selenium tests and it reports a test that takes 12 seconds as being slow (the duration is highlighted in red). In this context 12 seconds is fine.

How can I configure the threshold to 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Jest migrated from milliseconds to seconds

<strike>Jest allows configuration property `slowTestThreshold` which you can set in milliseconds.</strike>

Jest allows configuration property `slowTestThreshold` which you can set in seconds.

example `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    slowTestThreshold: 30
  };
};
```

this will show error if tests run for more than 30 seconds

Comment: This answer should be updated to show the code using seconds instead of milliseconds. Currently only @andrestone's answer seems correct. Maybe yours was at the time of writing?

Answer (score 6):

### Late 2020 update - previous answers are outdated

Configure [the `slowTestThreshold` in seconds, as shown in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#slowtestthreshold-number)

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    /* ... */
    slowTestThreshold: 30,
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Please try to add a sample code to you answer to make it more useful even without a link :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Jest` is currently hard-coded](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/b4897796bcbcb972234ef699b3e9e0f6b8724132/packages/jest-reporters/src/get_result_header.js#L44-L46) to consider any test running over 5 seconds as long:

```js
if (runTime !== null && runTime > 5) {
  testDetail.push(LONG_TEST_COLOR(runTime + 's'));
}
```

Looks like you would need to fork the repo or submit a PR if you wanted to change that.

Comment: This is not valid anymore. Check @andrestone 's answer.